# Windows 8 App CoreWindow coordinates are reported 20% larger under Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-10

Update 1&2: Check bottom of question

I have several games (built with Visual Studio 2012 C++ under Windows 8.0) on the Windows Store. These games have worked fine under Windows 8.0 and 8.1. Recently customers complained that, under Windows 10, the image is not centered and part of it 'spills' outside the screen.

I have reproduced the problem by installing Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 under Windows 10. The problem is that the window coordinates reported by the OS are about 20% larger than what they should be. For example, mouse move events on a 1366x768 window report coordinates up to 1645.783 x 925.301. The only time the window dimensions are correct (as obtained by CoreWindow::Bounds) is when the app first starts up -- any resize event will mess them up (mouse events are never correct).

The same issue occurs even if I create a blank new project based on the "Visual C++ >> Windows Store >> Direct3D App" template.

The "size of text, apps, and other items" option in Windows 10 is set to 100%, so I can't see how this could be a scaling issue.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

UPDATE 1: Upon further testing, this problem occurs only when the **desktop resolution height** is less than 942 pixels (width is irrelevant). For example, on a 1366x768 desktop the problem occurs, but on a 1280x960 it doesn't.

UPDATE 2: This really looks like a Windows 10 bug. Does anyone know how it can be reported to Microsoft?

Comment: I have the very same problem - in my case i noticed that all the $WindowsSDK pathes still point to Windows/Kits/8.0. I installed the windows 10 SDK, also the windows 8.1 SDK is there. My wild guess is we need to update visual studio or some crap like that.

Comment: Goin' to give VS 2015 a try now. Should have a proper way to do that platform targetting. fingers crossed.